# loop with list of months as input in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run a loop with months as the input. Moreover, I want to spot the number of times a given topic appears in a specific date. The way I am trying to do so is as follows?

```
for (i in c("January", "February", "March", "April", 
                "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")){
  print(length(which(data$Date == "i 2005" & data$Maxtopic == 3)))
}
```

Nevertheless, I get 0 as output for all the dates. Any ideas why?

Cheers,

Comment: Try `data$Date == sprintf("%s 2005", i)`. You attempt searches for the literal string `"i 2005"`. PS: There are probably easier and more efficient solutions than a loop. Hard to tell without a reproducible example.

Comment: Excellent thanks. You want to put it as an answer to get the points? Cheers

Comment: You actual problem is probably better solved by using `table(gsub(" 2005", "", data[data$Maxtopic == 3, "Date"], fixed = TRUE))`.

Comment: wow, indeed much better! Cheers.

Comment: It's worth noting that `month.name` will give you a string of all 12 months, without needing to type them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `data$Date == sprintf("%s 2005", i)`. Your attempt searches for the literal string "i 2005".

However, the `table` function was designed for this. Use `gsub` to remove the year:

```
table(gsub(" 2005", "", data[data$Maxtopic == 3, "Date"], fixed = TRUE))
```

PS: Next time please provide a reproducible example to enable development and testing of solutions.